# How to define class fields for Eloquent model

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I come to Laravel from Yii and Codeigniter. And can't find a solution how to describe class fields for Eloquent model. I want to know which variables available for this class. Problem is when I define variable **public** => when I try to use it, this variable is empty. If i define variable **protected** => when I use it all is fine, but this variable is not available for auto competition (because this var is protected).

Thanks!

```
class User extends Eloquent
{

...
protected $registered; // works, but not available
public $registered; // not works, always empty
var $registered; // not works, always empty
...

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eloquent's attributes work with an internal `attributes` array and rely on the magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods. However those will never get called when you define the variables. What you can do to get auto-completion and document the attributes is just add them in a docblock comment:

```
/**
 * @property bool $registered is the user registered?
 */
class User extends Eloquent
```

In fact the `@property` annotation is specifically [designed for *magic* properties](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html):

> @property shows a "magic" property variable that is found inside the class.